# Get the database name in which Stored Procedure exists

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having SQL server 2008 and i am having 10 different databases in it and now i want to search one stored procedure that in which database the stored procedure is present.

Mentioned as duplicate by some ..... with out reading my question properly. My Requirement is i need to verify 'SP_Email' procedure. I which database is this procedure exists.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try this:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'if exists(select 1 from [?].sys.objects where name=''SP_Email'')
select ''?'' as FoundInDatabase from [?].sys.objects where name=''SP_Email'''
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM sys.objects will check only in the drop down selected database only but not all databases.

Comment: @Dineshalla:- This query works perfectly fine. Tested and verified!

Comment: Ya i tried it is showing Command(s) completed successfully. What i am suppose to do. Pls update your query

Comment: @Dineshalla:- Click on the Results tab of your result window! :) And you will find the database name there

Comment: NO it is showing only messages tab. which version you are using.

Comment: I am using the SQL Server 2008 version. What abt you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73566/discussion-between-rahul-tripathi-and-dinesh-alla).

Comment: Press [Ctrl] + 'R' and see what you get?

Comment: It's just showing Commands completed successfully. No output.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this.

```
SELECT name DatabaseName
FROM sys.databases
WHERE OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.ProcedureNameHere', 'P') IS NOT NULL;
```

This will return the database(s) name in which this particular object exist.

Replace **ProcedureNameHere** with your procedure name. In your case it would be **SP_Email** Keep rest of the things as it is.

Answer (score 2):

you need to query `sys.databases` of master database to get list of databases and for each database name you get you need to query the `db_name.sys.procedures` to check if it exists.

try below query and give a feedback:

```
use master
go
declare @FullQuery varchar(max)
declare @DBName varchar(50)
set @FullQuery=''
declare cr cursor for select name from sys.databases where database_id > 4
open cr
fetch next from cr into @DBName
while(@@fetch_status=0)
begin
set @FullQuery=@FullQuery+
    ' select name  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from '+@DBName+'.sys.procedures where name like ''%proc_name%'' union'
fetch next from cr into @DBName
end
close cr
deallocate cr
set @FullQuery=substring(@FullQuery,1,len(@FullQuery)-5)
exec (@FullQuery)
```

Comment: I have to search in all databases.

Comment: No, Just wait I'll give the complete query, I was hurry in posting (posted it before initial edit of question)

Comment: Ya i will wait for your answer

Comment: Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the UNION operation.

Comment: Well, just try "select @FullQuery" instead of "exec (@FullQuery)" (last line) and see if you get something

Comment: @Dineshalla I'm waiting for your feedback

Comment: @Dineshalla, you hurried up a little, I was trying to fix the propabebly issue but you didn't wait, ok anyway

Comment: Update your query i will chose best. if your query works fine then i will go with your answer.

Comment: great, I did a small edit can you test it and give a feedback?

Comment: sorry, again , there was a type

Comment: Even if the above query works but it would be still not a performance effective query as using cursor is always a overburden. And why not use the build in functions and procedures which MSDN is providing :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi, you are right, but I'm not using sp_msforeachdb , because you have used it and I don't want do a copy

Comment: @Farhęg:- Yes I am not saying its wrong. But I was just trying to make a point of avoiding cursors ;)

Comment: You tried for me. I am happy with your response. Thank you Very much.

Comment: You are very welcome. but the answer of @RahulTripathi is better, you did well to accept it. good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('DataBase1.SchemaName.StoredProcedureName') / 
OBJECT_ID('DataBase2.SchemaName.StoredProcedureName') / 
OBJECT_ID('DataBase3.SchemaName.StoredProcedureName') /
...
```

It will return `NULL` if there is no such procedure. This will work if all databases are on same instance.